# Get counts of users based on days since last visit

Tags: t-sql

I can determine the number of users who last visited in a month by using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) from USERS WHERE DATEDIFF(month, LastAccessDate, GETDATE()) < 1
```

I would now like a query returning a count of users and the days since they have visited. So the results would look something like:

```
Count    |  Days Since Last Visit
100      |  1
200      |  2
```

How can I calculate the days since the last visit and group by that column?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ID) 'Count'
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, LastAccessDate, GETDATE()) 'Days Since Last Visit'
FROM Users
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, LastAccessDate, GETDATE())
```

The code is written exactly as you explained in your last sentence.

If you want to exclude users that have logged in today (which will have a 0 in the `Days Since Last Visit` column), the use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ID) 'Count'
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, LastAccessDate, GETDATE()) 'Days Since Last Visit'
FROM Users
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, LastAccessDate, GETDATE()) > 0
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, LastAccessDate, GETDATE())
```